# Save and restore form data in a Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, restore

In an app, I have a login VC (view controller) and the data in the next VC (name, address etc.) is about the user with that login info from a database on a server. I pass data from the first VC to the second VC using PrepareforSegue. But when I want to come back to the second VC from other (future) VCs all the data about the user is erased. What is the easiest/cheapest way to save data that could be viewed from multiple VCs (persistent data displayed in a VC that does not get lost when this disappears and then reappears). Does it have to be stored on the hard drive of the phone?

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults to make it persistent and available to all controllers

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html